# How to read and write a double array created on C++ from Inline Assembler?

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I want to manipulate a array created on C++ from inline aasembler, when I try using a one-dimensional array it works O.K, but when I use a multi-dimensional array I always get a Zero.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double matrix[2][2] = { {10, 20},{30, 40} };//I always get a Zero
    //double matrix[2] = { 50, 60 };//It works

    double temp = 987;

    _asm {
        mov esi, 0

        finit
        ; fld[matrix]
        fld matrix[esi]
        fstp temp
        fwait
    }

    cout << "temp: " << temp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to get the 30?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Your arrays if of DOUBLE which are 8 bytes (QWORD). You need to load with a QWORD override or `fld` tries to read it as a 4 byte FLOAT. `fld qword ptr matrix[esi]`. If you want the third element of a 2D array you can load ESI with the value 16. The first element (DOUBLE) is at 0, second element at 8, third element at 16, 4th element at 24 etc. Each element is 8 bytes in size and you need to pass the BYTE offset of an element. You could have also done `fld qwiord ptr matrix[16]` to get the third element which is the value 30.0

Comment: Thank you!!, I willl edit the question with your solution.

Comment: No don't edit the question with a solution. Create an actual answer and place the solution there. You are allowed and encouraged to write answers to your own question.

Comment: It's 2019, do you really need to use legacy x87 for compatibility with CPUs before Pentium 4 / AMD K8?  `movsd xmm0, [mem]` is easier and more efficient.  Generally only use x87 to take advantage of hardware support for 80-bit FP.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'm just starting with asm and I'm trying to solve very simple problems before reading a serious book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the @michael-petch comment, the solution is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double matrix[2][2] = { {10, 20},{30, 40} };
    double temp[2][2];
    double val = 5;

    _asm {
        mov esi, 0
        mov ecx, 4
        finit
        for1:
            fld val
            fld qword ptr matrix[esi]
            fadd
            fstp qword ptr temp[esi]
            add esi,8
        loop for1
        fwait
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cout << temp[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `finit`, the FPU is already initialized on program entry.  (Unless MSVC crap has reduced the internal precision to double or float instead of 80-bit total / 64-bit significand.)  https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/.  Anyway, `val` is a constant so you could load it outside the loop. 
 That would also avoid unbalancing the x87 stack (which you currently do with two `fld` but only one pop in the `fstp`).  So your loop will fail for counts > 8. You also don't need `fwait`; that's been a NOP since 286 I think.

Comment: All of this would have been simpler with `movaps xmm0, xmm1` (copy `val` that you loaded earlier); `addsd xmm0, matrix[esi]` ; `movsd temp[esi], xmm0` - no worries about unbalancing the FP stack.